# The Hash Table does not gives the desired output

Tags: java, data-structures, hash, hashtable

I tried to fill a Hash Table with contents of one String Array and then Match the Content of the Second Array, if it is all contained in the First Array.

e.g.

give me one grand today night - String A

give one grand today - String B

My Program should output Yes, as all the content of String B is included in A.

The detailed question is here: - https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-ransom-note/problem

Here is My Java Code:-

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int m = in.nextInt();
        int n = in.nextInt();
        String magazine[] = new String[m];
        for(int magazine_i=0; magazine_i < m; magazine_i++){
            magazine[magazine_i] = in.next();
        }
        String ransom[] = new String[n];
        for(int ransom_i=0; ransom_i < n; ransom_i++){
            ransom[ransom_i] = in.next();
        }

        Hashtable<Integer,String> hm = new Hashtable<Integer,String>();
        for(int magazine_i=0; magazine_i < m; magazine_i++){
            hm.put(1,magazine[magazine_i]);
            //System.out.println(magazine[magazine_i]);
        }

        boolean isavailable = false;

        for(int ransom_i=0; ransom_i < n; ransom_i++){
            isavailable = hm.containsValue(ransom[ransom_i]);
            //System.out.println(ransom[ransom_i]+" "+isavailable);
            if(isavailable==flase)
            {System.out.println("No"); break;}
        }

        if(isavailable==true)
            System.out.println("Yes");

    }
 }
```

Instead it gives False, the problem I think is that the Hash table cannot match contents of the Array and its Value.

Comment: Sorry sir! I tried reversing it, it still gives a wrong answer. I initially wrote the way you are telling. Thank you for notifying, I have corrected that in the question.

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Hashtable` contains only single key-value pair because of the way you initialize it:

```
   hm.put(1,magazine[magazine_i]);
```

Try to correct it first

By the way, your approach is wrong.

To generate the `ransom`, you must ensure that all word in `ransom` is contained in `magazine`, plus that the count of that word in the `magazine` should be greater than or equal to the corresponding count of that word in `ransom`.

That is, if `ransom` contains 4 words 'today' then in `magazine`, you must ensure that there are atleast 4 words 'today'.

Therefore, you should approach the problem like this:

1. From `magazine`, build a word count map for `magazine`: `HashMap<String, Integer> magazineWordCount`.
2. From `ransom`, build a word count map for `ransom`: `HashMap<String, Integer> ransomWordCount`
3. Loop over `ransom` keys (by `ransomWordCount.keySet()`), check that

   ```
    magazineWordCount.contains(word) && magazineWordCount.get(word) >= ransomWordCount.get(word)
   ```

Comment: I corrected it sir, added uniques keys to all element. Still does not helps in the output.

Comment: You can replace `HashMap` by `HashTable` if needed

Comment: This seems the answer, thank you for your valuable feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify you code by doing this

- get rid of prompting for input size
- Fail quickly

  ```
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter sentence 1");
  String s1 = in.nextLine();
  System.out.println("Enter sentence 2");
  String s2 = in.nextLine();

  List<String> s1List = Arrays.asList(s1.split(" "));
  for (String w : s2.split(" ")) {
      System.out.println("loooking for " + w);
      if (s1List.contains(w) == false) {
          System.out.println("Failed to find");
          return;
      }
  }
  System.out.println("yes");
  ```

**edit**

If you want to use a Hashtable then you can fill it up like

```
    String [] arr = s1.split(" ");
    Hashtable <Integer, String> s1ht = new Hashtable<Integer, String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        s1ht.put(i, arr[i]);
    }
```

All the other code is the same (only variable name will need to change)

Comment: Thank you , Scary Wombat.! I want to do this using an Hash Table instead.